# convert yyyy.mm.dd time.stamp to yyyy.mm time stamp in pandas python

Tags: pandas

I have a df indexed by a date time.stamp yyyymmdd. I want to truncate it to yyyy.mm My code follows:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=['date','bill_id','sponsor_id']) for f in glob.glob('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s11?_s_b')))
column_list = ['date', 'bill_id']

df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), inplace=True)
df.to_period(freq='M')
df.sort_values(by='date')

            date        bill_id     sponsor_id

date            
2007-01-04  2007-01-04  s103-110    1379
2007-01-04  2007-01-04  s68-110     7
2007-01-04  2007-01-04  s25-110     1380
2007-01-04  2007-01-04  s136-110    11
```

Comment: You mean you just want to change the display of the date rather than any intrinsic values? you can do `df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')`

Comment: Will it let me be able to perform group by and and value count my month?

Comment: By year and month, yes.  They will by unique string values, e.g. '2016-03'